# How to Update XML value in Textbox?

Tags: xml, textbox

I fetch the XML data in Textbox from Database.Now i want to make some changes and update in DB.when i try to make changes textbox not allowed text,but it remmove the data. MY code

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        string str = "select col1 from Table where Clo2='" + txt1.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        XmlReader xmlreader = command .ExecuteXmlReader();
        xmlreader.Read();
        txt2.Text = xml.ReadOuterXml();                     
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document .PreserveWhitespace = true;
        document .LoadXml(txt2.Text);

    }
```

how can i enter text in Textbox..plase give some suggistions...